# Setting a property in Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've spent too many hours trying to accomplish something that should be very simple, so reaching out to this group. I'm simply trying to update the value of a property of a Blazor form but it doesn't execute the code--it only renders the code on the browser page.

I'm trying to set the variable priorWorkspace to the value of rpt.WorkspaceName as @priorWorkspace = @rpt.WorkspaceName but it doesn't work and the rpt.WorkspaceName is rendered.

Obviously, I'm new at this, so be nice. :-)

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Workspace</th>
            <th>Report Name</th>
            <th>Report Desc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var rpt in rptObj)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (@priorWorkspace == @rpt.WorkspaceName)
                {
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@rpt.WorkspaceName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportDesc</td>
                    }
                else 
                {
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="@rpt.WorkspaceName" checked="@isChecked" @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxChanged(rpt, eventArgs.Value); }"></td>
                    <td>@rpt.WorkspaceName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportDesc</td>
                    }
            </tr>
            <code>@priorWorkspace = @rpt.WorkspaceName</code>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


@code {

    public string priorWorkspace = "";
    List<PowerBIWorkspace> rptObj;
}
```

Comment: `code` is an html element, like div, li, etc. It is not going to evaluate a c# expression. Do your logic in the `@code` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I didn't test it.

```
@{
    string priorWorkspace = "";
    foreach (var rpt in rptObj)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (priorWorkspace == rpt.WorkspaceName)
                {
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@rpt.WorkspaceName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportDesc</td>
                    }
                else 
                {
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="@rpt.WorkspaceName" checked="@isChecked" @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxChanged(rpt, eventArgs.Value); }"></td>
                    <td>@rpt.WorkspaceName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportName</td>
                    <td>@rpt.ReportDesc</td>
                    }
            </tr>

            priorWorkspace = rpt.WorkspaceName;
        }
}

@code {

    //public string priorWorkspace = "";
    List<PowerBIWorkspace> rptObj;
}
```

Comment: Henk, that works perfectly and it actually helps me understand how to implement inline code much better. Thank you for taking the time to answer!